# Construct String based off length of list

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

Say I have a list that looks like this.

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
```

I want to construct a string like this from the list.

```
'{(%s),(%s),(%s),(%s)}' % (x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3])
```

However, I want to be able to change the length of the string based on the length of x.

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

```
Output: {(1),(2),(3),(4)}
```

Comment: Do you mean adding padding to the list? to the start, end or between the elements in the string?

Comment: Please just add 2 example string outputs you want to generate, it'd help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'{%s}' % ','.join('(%s)' % element for element in x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'{%s}' % ','.join(['(%s)'] * len(x)) % tuple(x)
```